# Track USB activity on Windows

Tags: windows, usb

I want to know what happens in my USB Devices (file creation, file renamed, etc) **without** using an **external tool**.

I'm using Windows 7, can I enable some GPO to log these actions?

[Here](http://www.eventtracker.com/newsletters/tracking-removable-storage-windows-security-log/) the event 4663 is used. Can I use something like this on Windows 7 or Windows 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Without third party tools, no, it's not possible - the functionality was only introduced in Windows Server 2012, and subsequent releases: see [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn319046.aspx) for details (under the section header "What is the difference between audit policies located in Local Policies\Audit Policy and audit policies located in Advanced Audit Policy Configuration?" for some reason).